# libgdx using chartboost rewrded video, code is good but getting error

Tags: android, libgdx, chartboost

as i see in logcat I'm getting error

> E/ad: Request already in process for impression with location Game Over

everything else is ok but i can't see ad, what does this error mean ?

Comment: It means that you are already trying to show an ad. Your code is probably not good.

Comment: code is good, it didnt work for several hours, then it started working, idk what was wrong, i have not changed code

Comment: Could you please let me know how did you added Chartboost in libgdx? I am trying to add it but no success

Comment: @iappmaker it's not hard, just create interface in core project, and implement it from android project..